# Why do SCDF does not support JMS?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm evaluating the use of Spring-Cloud-DataFlow. I'm wondering why do it supports the use of Kafka and RabitMQ but does not support JMS? Is there a technical reasons? or is it just a mater of contributing and add the JMS support?

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of JMS-spec implementation from different vendors. In fact, we have an implementation for IBM MQ, Solace and ActiveMQ.

As for the support, since JMS is a spec and there is a variety of vendor-specific investments in the enterprise, we (spring) didn't want to ship binaries that involve vendor-specific licensing terms, so we have opened it up with the partners to support them instead. Example: Solace built a supported version of Solace PubSub+ implementation, and that's hosted in their GitHub, too.

Google PubSub and Azure Event Hubs are the other binder implementations, and they are supported and maintained by them directly. More details [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/#binder-implementations).

Lastly, from SCDF point-of-view, if the Spring Cloud Stream applications are bundled with the particular binder implementation, there's nothing extra required for SCDF. The SCDF-server orchestrates the deployment of the Spring Cloud Stream applications on the targeted platform.